# What is the usage of shift feature from scipy.ndimage.interpolation?

Tags: python

I am confused how to use the shift feature from scipy.ndimage.interpolation as I am working on a classification task. Can you help me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shift() function from the scipy.ndimage.interpolation module. For example,
shift(image, [2, 1], cval=0) shifts the image 2 pixels down and 1 pixel to the right.

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
shifted_digit_image=shift(some_digit_image,[2,1])
```

Hope this helps :)